# Georeferencing point clouds in deck.gl

Tags: reactjs, point-clouds, deck.gl, react-map-gl

I would like to present a point cloud of lidar data over a static map in deck.gl.

There is [an example](https://deck.gl/#/documentation/deckgl-api-reference/layers/point-cloud-layer) of a point cloud positioned on a map in the deck.gl docs.  But from the code it isn't clear to me how the example point cloud is georeferenced.  The other point cloud examples I've found in the deck.gl docs do not include maps.

Since my data is from a 'real world' measurement, I will need to ensure it is correctly aligned with the map.  How should I go about this?